# Chrome & Opera checkboxes are not being checked

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

First of all I want to say, that in FF (both Stable & Nightly) everything works fine.
In Opera and Chrome I get this: checkboxed not being checked.

I'm sorry the site is in russian, but I translated the elements that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Here's the site http://dstest.atservers.net/katalog

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

- Scroll the page down to the middle.
- Check the box in the left module (it's not shown as  checked)
- Do an action (scroll the page or chanage something in the    Inspect
  Element)
- And after that the box is marked as checked.

**The problem is, it's not marked as checked right when you do it and only after you scroll the page.**

As you see I got the **jQuery Waypoints** here, other stuff can be seen in the Inspect Element window.

**It works fine in Firefox (both Stable & Nightly).
It doesn't work in Chrome, Opera (didn't check Safari)**

There wasn't such a problem before I implemented the jQuery Waypoints.

**Information on the frameworks and CMS used:**

- Joomla 2.5
- T3-Framework
- Bootstrap 3
- Font-Awesome 4
- jQuery Waypoints

Comment: Works in chrome for me. Which version are you using?

Comment: Latest, 32. Did you try opera? Maybe its in my PC, but I doubt it. It's the same on the laptops I tested on.

Comment: Maybe the issue is something related to the js error, on console.

Comment: Can you please show your jquery code for checkbox?

Comment: There's no jquery code for the box. jQuery Waypoints is used to stick the module to the top of the page after it has reached a particular point of  the viewport.